# Can anyone see my CV before it has been "filed"?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv, privacy

If I've created and saved my CV but haven't filed it, can anyone see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can see it but you -- until you:

a) make it public (free, not yet implemented, but coming soon)

-or-

b) file it and make it searchable by employers ($29 / 3 years)

These are both off by default, so your CV is always 100% private until you decide it isn't.

Also, once you make a CV searchable by employers, you have the option to hide it again, so it can't be seen.

Comment: will a public CV be searchable by employers?

Comment: it's public web info, so it's searchable by anyone. However, there will be no indication of whether you're actually looking for work or not; that's the key distinction. We'll elaborate on this on the next podcast.