# How do I make my CV public in careers?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I've setup my CV but has not paid for the service yet. On the latest podcast, they mention that the CV can be published publicly. How do I do that, I can't find the option anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the previous incarnation it was [a coming soon thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25547/can-anyone-see-my-cv-before-it-has-been-filed).

In the Careers 2.0 version, it's as simple as clicking a "make profile public" button and picking out a display URL to hop along with it.

[image: sidebar of careers page]

Answer (score 1):

Public CVs are now available!  Go reserve yours now!

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/free-public-careers-cvs/